# run CASE statement inside loop

Tags: mysql, sql, loops, case

I have a following query that looks a bit dirty:

```
SELECT id, title, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN day = 1 THEN lunchStatus ELSE 0 END) '1',
    SUM(CASE WHEN day = 2 THEN lunchStatus ELSE 0 END) '2',
    SUM(CASE WHEN day = 3 THEN lunchStatus ELSE 0 END) '3',
    SUM(CASE WHEN day = 4 THEN lunchStatus ELSE 0 END) '4',
    SUM(CASE WHEN day = 5 THEN lunchStatus ELSE 0 END) '5',
    SUM(CASE WHEN day = 6 THEN lunchStatus ELSE 0 END) '6',
    SUM(CASE WHEN day = 7 THEN lunchStatus ELSE 0 END) '7',
    SUM(CASE WHEN day = 8 THEN lunchStatus ELSE 0 END) '8',
    SUM(CASE WHEN day = 9 THEN lunchStatus ELSE 0 END) '9',
    SUM(CASE WHEN day = 10 THEN lunchStatus ELSE 0 END) '10',
    SUM(CASE WHEN day = 11 THEN lunchStatus ELSE 0 END) '11',
    SUM(CASE WHEN day = 12 THEN lunchStatus ELSE 0 END) '12',
    SUM(CASE WHEN day = 13 THEN lunchStatus ELSE 0 END) '13',
    SUM(CASE WHEN day = 14 THEN lunchStatus ELSE 0 END) '14',
    SUM(CASE WHEN day = 15 THEN lunchStatus ELSE 0 END) '15',
    SUM(CASE WHEN day = 16 THEN lunchStatus ELSE 0 END) '16',
    SUM(CASE WHEN day = 17 THEN lunchStatus ELSE 0 END) '17',
    SUM(CASE WHEN day = 18 THEN lunchStatus ELSE 0 END) '18',
    SUM(CASE WHEN day = 19 THEN lunchStatus ELSE 0 END) '19',
    SUM(CASE WHEN day = 20 THEN lunchStatus ELSE 0 END) '20',
    SUM(CASE WHEN day = 21 THEN lunchStatus ELSE 0 END) '21',
    SUM(CASE WHEN day = 22 THEN lunchStatus ELSE 0 END) '22',
    SUM(CASE WHEN day = 23 THEN lunchStatus ELSE 0 END) '23',
    SUM(CASE WHEN day = 24 THEN lunchStatus ELSE 0 END) '24',
    SUM(CASE WHEN day = 25 THEN lunchStatus ELSE 0 END) '25',
    SUM(CASE WHEN day = 26 THEN lunchStatus ELSE 0 END) '26',
    SUM(CASE WHEN day = 27 THEN lunchStatus ELSE 0 END) '27',
    SUM(CASE WHEN day = 28 THEN lunchStatus ELSE 0 END) '28',
    SUM(CASE WHEN day = 29 THEN lunchStatus ELSE 0 END) '29',
    SUM(CASE WHEN day = 30 THEN lunchStatus ELSE 0 END) '30',
    SUM(CASE WHEN day = 31 THEN lunchStatus ELSE 0 END) '31'
FROM
(
    SELECT m.id, m.title, l.month, l.day, l.lunchStatus
FROM `months` m 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(SELECT MONTHNAME(issuedDateTime) as month, DAY(issuedDateTime) as day, lunchStatus, userId
 FROM lunch_status 
 WHERE userId = 134) l 
 ON m.title = l.month
    ) as s
    GROUP BY title
    ORDER BY id
```

I am getting the result-set as expected.

But I want to tidy and optimize the script, and hence run that long CASE statements inside a neat loop. Working with database is not my strong forte.

Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You are selecting 33 columns out of a table, and for the last 31 you are "massaging" the result independently for each column of the result. Yes, this looks as a repetition, but the fundamental fact is that you **ARE** handling (somehow) each column. As such, there is no much that can be done to improve this. Do you experience performance issues?

Comment: Performance-wise it seems to be no problem.
Can't it be run inside a loop or something?

Comment: run your script appending with explaing analysis ..then you will get to know the area of improvement

Comment: @Azima, the only way (I can think of right now) to run this as a loop is by using Dynamic SQL. Not recommented.

Comment: If you don't have performance issues, what do you want to optimise? A loop will always be slower.